# compound string comparison in nsis

Tags: nsis

How do I do a compound string comparison in NSIS?

essentially something like: `if ( str1 == "" || str2 == "" ) ...`

```
strcpy $1 "c:\foo"
strcpy $2 "d:\bar"

${if} strcmp $1 ""
${orif} strcmp $2 ""
   MessageBox MB_OK "one or both are empty"
${else}
   messagebox mb_ok "both are not"
${endif}
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StrCmp` is the low-level instruction at the heart of NSIS string comparisons but when using the LogicLib you must use the correct operators: `==`, `!=`, `S==` or `S!=` (all of them are listed at the top of LogicLib.nsh and the case-insensitive operators use `StrCmp` internally)

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Section
StrCpy $1 "c:\foo"
StrCpy $2 "d:\bar"

${If} $1 == ""
${OrIf} $2 == ""
   MessageBox MB_OK "one or both are empty"
${Else}
   MessageBox MB_OK "both are not"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```